# Autocomplete not returning output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

How to retrieve the query results by appending the form field values dynamically by using ajax?

```
 <script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("textbox").autocomplete({
        source: function(query, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/xxx/sample.cfc?method=queries&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchKeyword: query.term
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    response(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

I've tried the code below, but am unable to get the output. Is this way correct?

How do I fetch the records by passing `searchKeyword` to sample.cfc? What is the logic to be written in sample.cfc?

Comment: try select2 : http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: I think you are doing things backwards.  I think you should get your cfc working first before you start calling it with ajax.  The reason is that if you don't write it perfectly the first time, it's a lot easier to troubleshoot using coldfusion and nothing else.

Comment: is "textbox" the ID? be sure to use $("#textbox").autocomplete if it is. I agree with Dan, make sure your cfc produces the desired json depending on your query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your only problem is that you're not targetting the text box properly.
Changing your code to

```
<input type="text" id="textbox">
 <script> 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox").autocomplete({
        source: function(query, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/xxx/sample.cfc?method=queries&returnformat=json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchKeyword: query.term
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    response(result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
  });
 </script>
```

submits correctly for me, with firebug showing the URL params (after i typed my name into the input field) as:

method  queries

returnformat    json

searchKeyword   andrew

(note : if you're inside a  tag you'll have to change the selector to ##textbox)

An incredibly simple **sample.cfc** which just returns your search keyword back to you would look like

```
component{

    remote function queries() {
        return url.searchKeyword;
    }

}
```

Unless this is just a learning exercise for you, i suggest using a jquery widget to save you writing a whole autocompleter yourself..